# Highlight a button in Windows Forms

Tags: winforms, button, highlight

When i press a button, i start the code with Form disabling and end it with Form enabling.
Meanwhile the pressed button appears highligthed. That button executes in sequence the functions of the buttons inside the group next to it.
[How it appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8I9z.png)
Is there a way of highlight the button associated with the function beeing executed ?

I tried buttonx.Focus() but it does nothing :(

Comment: If you have synchronous code, then the UI is repainted when that code terminates its activity. You could refresh the Button that is meant to receive the focus (assuming it's also enabled). Calling `Refresh()`, the affected UI is repainted immediately

Comment: There is also the possibility to change the background color of the button.